# Recover corrupt MTS file via ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, data-recovery

I have many large video files from an overseas trip. 90% of them are great, but there are a few I recorded on a dodgy SD card which are unable to play for some reason. They are all .MTS files.

In VLC, an error appears when trying to play them:

```
Unidentified codec:
VLC could not identify the audio or video codec
```

I don't know much about video files or codecs, but I am savvy enough to use ffmpeg, which I thought might be my best bet.

I attempted this on one of the files (call it 'input.MTS'):

```
ffmpeg -i input.MTS output.mp4
```

The result was this:

```
ffmpeg version N-82597-gd316b21 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 40.100 / 55. 40.100
  libavcodec     57. 66.106 / 57. 66.106
  libavformat    57. 58.100 / 57. 58.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 67.100 /  6. 67.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
[adp @ 0000000000026380] Format adp detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, adp, from 'input.MTS':
  Duration: 00:05:38.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 438 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: adpcm_dtk, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.58.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.66.106 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (adpcm_dtk (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=     312kB time=00:05:38.68 bitrate=   7.6kbits/s speed=33.7x
video:0kB audio:250kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 25.134468%
[aac @ 00000000025c5ba0] Qavg: 65531.879
```

The output.mp4 file now plays in VLC without error, and is 5 minutes and 38 seconds long. However, there is no audio or video.

Also, input.MTS is ~18 MB, and output.mp4 is ~0.313 MB.

What is the correct way to recover this video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct way to recover this video?

You **cannot** recover anything, from [**this file**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwVBB1L9z7kWTHJuVWMtTDB0d2M/view?usp=sharing), because it does **not contain** any audio/video data.

Each and every single byte in the file has the maximum amount `FF` as its hex value (or decimal `255`). See image below (showing some of) your file's bytes.

From this input I think FFmpeg has just guessed that your file must be some kind of PCM (uncompressed audio). The lack of a recognized format's header forces it to go a step further and assume your data as some ADPCM since that format does not always involve header data).

FFmpeg says : `Stream #0:0: Audio: adpcm_dtk, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p`

VLC says : `VLC could not identify the audio or video codec`

As shown below there's nothing in file bytes to confirm actual format (is image? video? or audio?). Data could be PCM audio or could be just an all-white image (one white pixel = `FF FF FF`).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. What program did you use to look at this? I might have a look at my other files to see whether there's anything in them.

Comment: Hi. Any freeware hex editor is fine, but I used [**HxD**](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) for Windows (tip: make sure in **Options** --> **View** you set "Offset Base" to decimal, for easier checking of byte positions).

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons I suspect here. One is the ffmpeg command you are using not enough I think. Try below command once or look [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/how-can-i-convert-mts-file-avchd-to-mp4-by-ffmpeg-without-re-encoding-h264-v).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mts -y -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

Second, I suspect VLC, because it not that stable. You can try playing it in mplayer or ffplay or any other player.

Comment: Thanks, however I still get an error: Unknown encoder 'libfaac' [full output here](https://pastebin.com/raw/cAEvT9pL). 

I have also tried other media players and get the same result.

Comment: That means your ffmpeg does not have libfaac encoder enabled. You can use other codecs such as mp3 or mp2 for audio.

Comment: libfaac support was removed from ffmpeg. Use the native FFmpeg AAC encoder instead (`-c:a aac`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just tried this: `ffmpeg -i input.mts -y -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4` (simply omitted the audio codec). It now runs error-free, but the file is only 313 kbs and contains no video. [Full output here](https://pastebin.com/raw/BfbFnD2w).

Comment: Can you use _-strict experimental_ option and see?

Comment: After trying `ffmpeg -i input.mts -y -vcodec mpeg4 -strict experimental output.mp4`, I seem to get the same output.

Comment: Can you upload video? If it is not very big

Comment: [Here's one of the smaller ones](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwVBB1L9z7kWTHJuVWMtTDB0d2M/view?usp=sharing) I have, it should only be a few seconds long and is 4.21 MB.